# Custom drawing in Google Maps Android API v2 (curved Polyline)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a `MapView` (provided by Google Maps Android API v2) and what I'm trying to achieve should be simple enough, which is simply to **draw a curved `Polyline`**.

To be specific, I have an array of `LatLng`s and rather than having them joined at sharp angles, I want to have the route rounded off nicely, so that the line through the points follows a curve rather than straight lines and sharp angles.

Now, this used to be possible in the old Google Maps API by creating a custom `Overlay`, overriding `draw()`, and then manually drawing onto the map (e.g. with a custom `Paint` and `Path` with the desired settings).

Unfortunately it seems that in v2, Google have removed the `Overlay` class and moved to higher-level abstractions which no longer provide access to the `draw()` method. `PolylineOptions` is fairly basic and doesn't provide any option to draw a curved line.

**Is there any way to override `draw()` or use other features of Google Maps API v2 in order to draw a curved `Polyline`?**

There are a few questions already on SO which cover this issue, however there isn't really a satisfactory answer as yet:

[Custom Overlays in Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364977/custom-overlays-in-google-maps-api-v2)

[Overrinding draw() in customized MapView in Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966565/overrinding-draw-in-customized-mapview-in-google-maps-android-api-v2)

I'm sure there *must* be a way to do custom drawing on Google Maps v2, and whilst creating a custom overlay `View` and drawing onto that once the coordinates are synced up with the map is an option, it will quickly get extremely complicated when dealing with scaling and panning the map, so it's something I want to avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an abstract class CanvasTileProvider() where you just have to override the onDraw method, in order to perform your drawing as usual into a Canvas. A TileProjection object, which is passed into the onDraw method in addition, helps you to do the back and forth calculation between LatLng and points on the Canvas.
The only limitation is, that tiles are usually loaded only once. So this way of drawing into the map is suitable for shapes which do not frequently change. Thus it may not be suitable if your array of LatLng objects is continuously changing (e.g. because it shows the current movement of the device).

You can find the CanvasTileProvider class in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382823/google-maps-api-v2-draw-part-of-circle-on-mapfragment/20408460#20408460)